# Is it possible to start an IPython session via ssh and log back in later?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, ipython

I work on a machine per ssh where I run `ipython` for interactive work. Can I start a long-running Python function from IPython, sever the ssh connection and log back in later into the IPython session to observe the result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Use `screen`, `tmux` (superior), or similar software. Both use the concept of sessions that you attach to and detach from.

With `tmux`:

1. Run `tmux` and then `ipython`.
2. When you're finished, `<Ctrl+b> d` to detach. You're back in the normal shell.
3. When you come back, `tmux attach` will take you back to `ipython`.

Using screen, the commands are `screen`, `<Ctrl+a> <Ctrl+d>` and `screen -r`.

Comment: Could you describe how to use `screen` or `tmux` in combination with `ipython`?

Comment: Sure. Give me a minute

Comment: Works like a charm with `tmux`. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds great, but I wonder if a detach really severs the ssh connection, or just puts it into the background. So can you reboot with a detached ssh and attach again?

Comment: @Jakob you ssh and invoke `tmux` in the *remote* shell, not in the local shell

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn Thank to the answer, I got it detached. My workflow is as follows: SSH to the server->`tmux`->`ipython notebook`->open browser in my local machine and run the notebook->`detach`. I am wondering if I can exit the SSH, close my local machine and return back using `tmux attach` on the remote shell with notebook kernel still running.